# How can create multiple adapters(Like Prisma and Redis) in auth.ts file in Next.js 13?

Tags: typescript, next.js, redis, next-auth

I wanna add two adapter authentication flow but in nextjs does not allowed two adapter same time. How can add ? Should I supposed to be create custom adapter for Redis usage ?

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
**adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma), ..ExampleAdapter(...),**

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
**adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma), UpstashRedisAdapter(redis),**